# Efficiently replacing multiple values in a column

Tags: r, sapply

I have a table which looks like this, where I have multiple values in two identical columns which must be replaced in one column like so:

Before

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| Default1 | Default 1 |
| Default2 | Default 2 |
| Default3 | Default 3 |
| Default4 | Default 4 |
| Default5 | Default 5 |
| Default6 | Default 6 |

After

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| Default1 | Q10 |
| Default2 | Q10 |
| Default3 | Q10 |
| Default4 | B12 |
| Default5 | B12 |
| Default6 | B12 |

My issue is that the table is 135 rows long, and I don't want to use this:

`Data.dat$Column_B[Data.dat$Column_B == "default55"] <- "Q10"`

a million times.

What is the most efficient way I could accomplish this goal?

I have tried individual replace functions, which work well...but aren't efficient.

I also tried sapply functions (in [this video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CaWjk53uXU0)), but all of the values are replaced in both columns.

If I didn't have to replace only one column, the sapply function would be perfect!

I've tried recode, but get a `operator is invalid for atomic vectors error` which I can't seem to solve.

Example recode below:

`Data.dat$Column_B<-recode(Data.dat$Column_B, "c('default1','default2','default3','default4','default5','default6','default7')='Q10'")`

Comment: You haven't given us any rules to help you with replacement. Pretend someone else wrote this question and try and answer it and you'll see what I mean. There isn't enough there to create your "after" scenario. Is there a mapping table that lets you know what to replace a combination of "default" and a number with? `dat[1:100000,"b"] <- "C10"` is instant so some more clarity would help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not sure if I understand what the issue is, but I know which cells need to be recoded to what values. 

They're all predictable values. In the case above, "default1,"default2",and"default3" needed to be recoded to Q10, and the same with 4,5, and 6 needing to be recoded to B12.

For argument's sake, we can assume that the sections which need to be recoded are in chunks of 5.

So 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `case_match` of `dplyr`?

### Data example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Column_A = c("Default1", "Default2", "Default3", "Default4", "Default5", "Default6"),
  Column_B = c("Default 1", "Default 2", "Default 3", "Default 4", "Default 5", "Default 6")
)
```

### Use case_match

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(Column_B = case_match(
    Column_B,
    c("Default 1", "Default 2", "Default 3") ~ "Q10",
    c("Default 4", "Default 5", "Default 6") ~ "B12"
  ))

df_new
```

```
> df_new
  Column_A Column_B
1 Default1      Q10
2 Default2      Q10
3 Default3      Q10
4 Default4      B12
5 Default5      B12
6 Default6      B12
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do!

This works perfectly.